# How can deploy node.js application in openshift

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I created node.js project, with express and angularjs and mongodb.
How can i deploy it to Openshift
the project structure look like this

My user name for the openshift is admin
password is X5900XJSLW4
db name is : topic

Now these are just fake , but they look like this. thanks

THIS WORK LOCALLY VERY FINE, BUT I GET Service Temporarily Unavailable @
http://topic-aggregator16.rhcloud.com/

error log found her
https://github.com/chihabSD/TopicAggregator/blob/master/images/errorlog.png

I REALLY NEED THIS TO WORK ASAP

```
    config.db.mongo = {};
config.web.port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.PORT || process.env.WEB_PORT || 8080;
config.web.ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.IP;
config.db.mongo.url = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/topic';
```

Comment: Only the connection part, i am worried about, not thing else, and its working fine locally

Comment: I got waiting for connection " port 27017 and authnticate admin db, usin the rhc tail, any help

Comment: look @ the code again, i have just included the connection section, this is really taking so long. thank in advance My user name for the openshift is admin
password is X5900XJSLW4
db name is : topic

Answer (score 5):

> To deploy an existing project into openshift you need to modify your
>   **package.json** and **server.json** files:

---

*package.json*

- Add the server.js file to the **main** key
- Add a start script in the **scripts** key

  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "node server.js",
   }

**example**

```
{
      "name": "to-do",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Simple todo app",
      "main": "server.js",
      "scripts": {
           "start": "node server.js",
           "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
       },
      "keywords": [
          "node",
          "angular"
      ],
      "dependencies" : {
          "express"    : "~4.7.2",
          "mongoose"   : "~3.6.2",
          "morgan"     : "~1.2.2",
          "body-parser": "~1.5.2",
          "method-override": "~2.1.2"
      },
      "author": "atefth@gmail.com",
      "license": "MIT"
}
```

---

*server.js*

- Add dynamic port from the openshift env
- Add dynamic IP from the openshift env

  ```
  var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

  var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

  app.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function () {

      console.log( "Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port " + server_port  );

  });
  ```

> Now you can use the rhc --from-code flag to deploy a project from existing code

```
rhc app create appName nodejs-0.10 -s --from-code=https://github.com/username/app.git
```

**UPDATE**

> If you're using mongodb you need to update your server.js file

```
if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD){
  connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ':' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + '/' +
  process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME;
  config.db.mongo.url = connection_string;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: that what i have right now, i just dont understand the idea behind openshift , its working fine locally but i did pushed it to openshift, but i got service not available or something like that.

Comment: the server now, i listening to it via port 3000, do i delete that,with code you sent me, or leave as its.

Comment: i used your code, but i got waiting for connection @ port 21017 and authnticate admin db etc. i used rhc tail, to view error log, i also used the code supplied above, but no luck, my db as username, password, and its own name in openshift,and thats why i am facing trouble deploying it.

Comment: I see, you must be using mongodb, in that case can you please post your error logs? Use this command to grab your log - **rhc tail -a myapp**

Comment: here is the error log https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chihabSD/TopicAggregator/master/images/errorlog.png

Comment: can you post the whole output from the start please?

Comment: Please refer to the UPDATE section of my answer, I think adding that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, OpenShift Online (V2) will publish connection information to your application using environment variables (https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/environment-variables.html#listen).

Your nodejs webservice will need to use this information to connect to OpenShift's load-balancers.

For this example code, you would need to change

```
config.web.port = process.env.PORT || process.env.WEB_PORT || 3000;
config.web.ip = process.env.IP;
```

to:

```
config.web.port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.PORT || process.env.WEB_PORT || 3000;
config.web.ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.IP;
```

For more information, see https://developers.openshift.com/languages/nodejs/environment-variables.html#listen

Npm modules [`cloud-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloud-env) or [`config-multipaas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config-multipaas) may also be helpful if you prefer to stick with simpler, vendor-neutral application config strings (normalized to `PORT` and `IP`)